# mktime returns -1 but I'm expecting my tm struct to be valid

Tags: c

```
timeStruct  @0x13b123b0 tm
    tm_hour     0   int
    tm_isdst    0   int
    tm_mday     1   int
    tm_min      0   int
    tm_mon      0   int
    tm_sec      33  int
    tm_wday     4   int
    tm_yday     0   int
    tm_year     70  int
```

This is my struct as represented by QTcreators memory watch.

with this as parameter to a call of `mktime()`

```
struct tm *timeStruct;
//[...]
time_t timeOrigin = mktime(timeStruct);
```

`timeOrigin` becomes -1.

There are questions out here asking for the same.

But they all were solved by the hint, that the tm_year field is not years since 1970 but years since 1900. I'm aware of this and also respecting it.

What confuses me further is:

man pages like: http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime

explain that mktime doesn't change the structs members if it returns -1. In my case it did adjust in previous cases `tm_wday` and `tm_yday`, while returning -1.

I can't find any error regarding this by reading stderr, after mktime returning `-1` aswell.

So whats going on here?

Comment: "If the specified broken-down time cannot be represented as calendar time (seconds since the Epoch), mktime() returns (time_t) -1 and does not alter the members of the broken-down time structure. " But maybe I read it out of the context. But anyway my problem is at it is.

Comment: I see that now: you misquoted it.

Comment: @WeatherVane: so it belongs to a context thats not given for me? (In that case I'll take that info out)

Comment: The two members it modified, `tm_wday` and `tm_yday`, are the ones that it says it ignores. So it does not affect the data you passed it.

Comment: @WeatherVane: yeah I know. but I found it strange anyway.

Comment: Try `tm_mday     2`.  If that works, then [@chqrlie](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36137092/2410359) has the answer.

Comment: I'll try settin isdst to 1. What would be representing exactly what I want if he should be right.

Comment: What timezone are you in?  Recall that `mktime()` works on local time.

Comment: I'm in germany but its actually still winter time, so gmt. In 5 days it'll become gmt +1

Comment: "mktime doesn't change the structs members if it returns -1. "  --> The C11 spec doe not specify that.  It is silent on what happens to `struct tm` on error.

Comment: Are you sure that Germany = GMT? I just looked up local time in Berlin, One hour ahead of UK (which *is* GMT).

Comment: Ill check that. If im wrong it is gmt + 1 and will go to gmt + 2

Comment: OP's timestamp is 1970-Jan-1 00:00:33 standard time in Germany.  Agree with @Weather Vane, that is 1 hour ahead of GMT/UTC.

Comment: Yeah its actually gmt +1 so is that whats wrong here? Or not causing my problem anyway? Is it because of the isdst fkag beeing zero? Or have i by creating tm structs by hand thinking of my timezone aswell?

Comment: Just try `time_t t = 0; puts(ctime(&timer));` and see what local time you get.  If you specify a local time before that, `mktime()` likely will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mktime` returns -1 because the `tm` structure values, interpreted as a time and date expressed in local time, fall outside the valid range. As quoted from the man page: *If the specified broken-down time cannot be represented as calendar time (seconds since the Epoch), `mktime()` returns `(time_t)-1` and does not alter the members of the broken-down time structure.*

You are probably located east of Greenwich, meaning that 1/1/1970 0:00:00 local time falls before the beginning of the Unix Epoch that started on 1/1/1970 0:00:00 UTC.

Comment: The isdst flag is zero so for mktime this shouldnt matter if I understood it correct so in this direction isn't it mattering, is it?

Comment: `isdst` (if set) is used *as well as* the local time adjustment.

Comment: @Zaibis: `isdst` is used by `mktime` as extra information to distinguish between regular time and daylight savings time which is optionally used in many time zones and locations. It is actually necessary to tell the exact UTC time for the ambiguous 1 hour overlap when switching back to regular time in the fall.  There is no standard function to convert UTC broken down time to a unix time value.

Answer (score 0):

`mktime` expects a pointer of type `struct tm` as it's first argument.

Here is an example, how you can use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&(time_t){time(NULL)});
    printf("Today is           %s", asctime(&tm));
    tm.tm_mon -= 100;  // tm_mon is now outside its normal range
    time_t t = mktime(&tm); // recalculate tm
    printf("100 months ago was %s", asctime(&tm));
}
```

Comment: my time sttruct is a pointer. I thought this was self explaining since otherwise I would have had to call it this way: `mktime((struct tm*)timeStruct);` Added it fo clarification